# Maven Life Cycle Exception

Tags: java, maven

The below exception occurs in command prompt. Not able to resolve this exception and unable to understand it. Can someone explain what went wrong.

```
C:\Projects\POC2\TestingAutomationReportingTool>mvn -s settings.xml clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestingAutomationReportingTool 0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.088s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 20 11:22:25 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "ûs". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase o
r a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artif
act-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, ini
tialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resource
s, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, genera
te-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, t
est, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-inte
gration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, p
re-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhase NotFoundException
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `mvn clean`?

Comment: I tried mvn clean, mvn clean install, mvn eclipse:eclipse, with settings.xml parameter and without it. Getting the same exception.

Comment: Ok. Please post your pom file! Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: Thanks for checking, got resolved, seems to be some issue with settings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be some issue with settings.xml. The issue got resolved after removing all commented sections of settings.xml