# I am getting LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException for Selenium Automation

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation, maven-plugin

I am getting **LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException for Selenium Automation** while running "mvn clean verify -P it -Dit.test=AA_SetupIT, " checked following the steps

```
 1. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException.
 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397717/maven-life-cycle-exception.
 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930469/unknown-lifecycle-phase-mvn-you-must-specify-a-valid-lifecycle-phase-or-a-goa
 4. mvn install -DskipTests
 5. Clean project
 6. maven update
 7. Download the repo again and run.
```

**Any other suggestions? Appreciate your help. Thanks**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do the following as steps mentioned, it helped me

```
 1. Download the repo and import project
 2. Restart IDE
 3. Clean project
 4. maven update from IDE
Now from Terminal
 5. mvn compiler:compile
 6. mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:compile
 7. mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile
 8. maven clean install
 9. mvn install -DskipTests
 10. Run project from terminal : mvn clean verify -P it -Dit.test=AA_SetupIT,<Class name without space>
```

Comment: That is just nonsense.

Comment: Hello @JFabianMeier What do you want to mean?

Comment: I mean that your answer is completely wrong and you have no idea how Maven works.

Comment: But it worked for me

Comment: So? Read a bit about Maven, then come back and improve your answer. This is like "My car did not start, so I painted it blue, and then it worked again."